# Randomly splitting data from a grouped dataset

Tags: r

The following is a sample of my dataset.

```
plotID  Rs.ten  Corr.Rs
1   4.7 2.434437263
1   5.4 2.753744943
1   4   2.044908476
1   0   1.19251
1   1.2 1.84929
1   1.7 1.0755
1   2   1.55399
1   4.5 1.45883
1   3   1.12485
1   4.4 1.92245
1   3.6 1.77914
2   -8.0    0.027792795
2   0.2 0.988443802
2   3.5 0.937311439
2   4   1.007496802
2   5.6 1.738293766
2   6.5 1.722974764
2   6.4 1.590481774
2   5.5 1.097063592
2   5.2 1.389683585
2   6.4 1.392490686
2   6.6 1.812855123
2   5   1.42508238
2   0.4 0.90678
2   3.1 1.00162
2   2.7 0.7914
2   5.9 0.81313
2   4.9 0.89668
2   6.3 1.25597
2   4.7 1.03459
3   5   2.265195289
3   5.3 1.655801734
3   4.4 3.593587609
3   4   3.668348047
3   5.2 2.459742028
3   4.3 3.128687638
3   0.7 2.55316
3   3   2.5708
3   2.8 1.34671
3   2.6 1.90105
3   5.6 1.56052
3   4.2 2.26067
3   4.7 2.22488
3   3.7 2.91198
```

I have 36 groups represented by `plotID`.  I want to split the dataset into training and testing datasets (60/40, respectively) for each group (`plotID`).

In other words, I need a function that will randomly select 60% of the data from `plotID` 1, `plotID` 2, `plotID` 3, etc. for training and leave the remaining 40% from each `plotID` for testing. I came close using the following link: [Randomly split data by criterion into training and testing data set using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518982/randomly-split-data-by-criterion-into-training-and-testing-data-set-using-r), however, this simply split the entire dataset 60/40 by the total number of groups, not from within each group.

Seems like I'm missing something simple here, but I just can't see it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
set.seed(123)
ind_train <- lapply(split(seq(1:nrow(df)), df$plotID), function(x) sample(x, floor(.6*length(x))))
ind_test <- mapply(function(x,y) setdiff(x,y), x = split(seq(1:nrow(df)), df$plotID), y = ind_train)
```

Which gives you:

```
 df[unlist(ind_test),]
   plotID Rs.ten    Corr.Rs
2       1    5.4 2.75374494
3       1    4.0 2.04490848
5       1    1.2 1.84929000
6       1    1.7 1.07550000
9       1    3.0 1.12485000
12      2   -8.0 0.02779279
15      2    4.0 1.00749680
16      2    5.6 1.73829377
17      2    6.5 1.72297476
23      2    5.0 1.42508238
27      2    5.9 0.81313000
29      2    6.3 1.25597000
30      2    4.7 1.03459000
32      3    5.3 1.65580173
33      3    4.4 3.59358761
34      3    4.0 3.66834805
39      3    2.8 1.34671000
41      3    5.6 1.56052000
44      3    3.7 2.91198000
> df[unlist(ind_train),]
   plotID Rs.ten   Corr.Rs
4       1    0.0 1.1925100
8       1    4.5 1.4588300
11      1    3.6 1.7791400
10      1    4.4 1.9224500
7       1    2.0 1.5539900
1       1    4.7 2.4344373
22      2    6.6 1.8128551
28      2    4.9 0.8966800
21      2    6.4 1.3924907
19      2    5.5 1.0970636
26      2    2.7 0.7914000
18      2    6.4 1.5904818
20      2    5.2 1.3896836
25      2    3.1 1.0016200
13      2    0.2 0.9884438
24      2    0.4 0.9067800
14      2    3.5 0.9373114
31      3    5.0 2.2651953
35      3    5.2 2.4597420
42      3    4.2 2.2606700
40      3    2.6 1.9010500
37      3    0.7 2.5531600
36      3    4.3 3.1286876
38      3    3.0 2.5708000
43      3    4.7 2.2248800
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `stratified` function from my "splitstackshape" package:

Here's what 60% of the sample data you shared would look like (as far as number of elements per group):

```
> table(mydf$plotID) * .6

   1    2    3 
 6.6 11.4  8.4
```

Load "splitstackshape" and draw the sample:

```
> library(splitstackshape)
> out <- stratified(mydf, "plotID", .6, bothSets = TRUE)
```

The result is a `list` with two `data.table`s, one for the sample (60%) and one for what's left over (40%):

```
> str(out)
List of 2
 $ SAMP1:Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 26 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ plotID : int [1:26] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ Rs.ten : num [1:26] 2 4.4 3.6 3 4 0 4.7 5.9 6.5 6.4 ...
  ..$ Corr.Rs: num [1:26] 1.55 1.92 1.78 1.12 2.04 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ SAMP2:Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 18 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ plotID : int [1:18] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ Rs.ten : num [1:18] 5.4 1.2 1.7 4.5 -8 3.5 5.2 5 0.4 3.1 ...
  ..$ Corr.Rs: num [1:18] 2.7537 1.8493 1.0755 1.4588 0.0278 ...
  ..- attr(*, "sorted")= chr "plotID"
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
> lapply(out, function(x) table(x$plotID))
$SAMP1

 1  2  3 
 7 11  8 

$SAMP2

1 2 3 
4 8 6
```

---

It's generally more convenient to keep related data together in a `list`, but if you want separate objects, you can use `list2env`, like this:

Notice that I'm starting with just one object in my workspace:

```
ls()
# [1] "mydf"
list2env(stratified(mydf, "plotID", .6, bothSets = TRUE), envir = .GlobalEnv)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

I now have three objects:

```
ls()
# [1] "mydf"  "SAMP1" "SAMP2"
head(SAMP1)
#    plotID Rs.ten  Corr.Rs
# 1:      1    2.0 1.553990
# 2:      1    1.7 1.075500
# 3:      1    4.5 1.458830
# 4:      1    3.6 1.779140
# 5:      1    4.0 2.044908
# 6:      1    5.4 2.753745
nrow(SAMP1)
# [1] 26
head(SAMP2)
#    plotID Rs.ten  Corr.Rs
# 1:      1    4.7 2.434437
# 2:      1    1.2 1.849290
# 3:      1    3.0 1.124850
# 4:      1    4.4 1.922450
# 5:      2    4.0 1.007497
# 6:      2    5.5 1.097064
> nrow(SAMP2)
# [1] 18
```

Comment: your package is super helpful. However, I can't seem to figure out the `Reshape` function to get each data.table into a separate dataframe.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding this function? Would it be possible to demonstrate with this example?

Comment: @woodland_creature, use [`list2env`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list2env.html) from base R with the environment set to `.GlobalEnv`. I'm posting from my phone right now otherwise I would update with an example.

Comment: @woodland_creature, I've updated my answer to show how to get the two data.tables as separate objects.

Comment: Gotcha. Yep that worked as well. Thanks for your help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sample() https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html

```
sample(x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
```

You could pass a vector of keys to your data as x and grab sub sets from that in order to get a sub sub set from your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(1234)
df.split <- ddply(df, .(plotID), mutate, set=sample(c("train", "test"), length(plotID0, replace=T, prob=c(0.6, 0.4))
testSet <- subset(df.split, set == "test")
trainSet <- subset(df.split, set == "train")
```