# Specify a blocking factor in H2O

Tags: r, h2o

In the R version of H2O, is it possible to specify a blocking factor when splitting data in training/validation/test sets and/or when doing cross-validation?

I'm working on a clinical dataset with multiple observations from the same patient that should be kept together during these operations.

If this is not possible to do within the H2O framework then suggestions on how to achieve this in R and integrate with H2O functions would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: This questions seems to address how to do this in base R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518982/randomly-split-data-by-criterion-into-training-and-testing-data-set-using-r

Comment: We have a ticket open for this already: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4442  I just added this to the roadmap for the next major release -- hopefully it will get implemented soon, but I can't make any guarantees. (I've personally wanted this for a while).

Comment: Thanks @ErinLeDell. Do you have a working example of how to encode the fold_column given a column of IDs? I.e., an example of this: `The user-specified fold_column method requires the user to code the stratification-by-ID themselves, which is a pain.`

Answer (score 1):

When using H2O-3 with cross validation, you can tell the training algorithm which fold number an observation belongs to with the `fold_column` parameter.  See:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/fold_column.html

The code example below (copied from the link above) shows folds being assigned randomly.  But you could alternately write a piece of code to assign them specifically yourself.

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# import the cars dataset:
# this dataset is used to classify whether or not a car is economical based on
# the car's displacement, power, weight, and acceleration, and the year it was made
cars <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/junit/cars_20mpg.csv")

# convert response column to a factor
cars["economy_20mpg"] <- as.factor(cars["economy_20mpg"])

# set the predictor names and the response column name
predictors <- c("displacement","power","weight","acceleration","year")
response <- "economy_20mpg"

# create a fold column with 5 folds
# randomly assign fold numbers 0 through 4 for each row in the column
fold_numbers <- h2o.kfold_column(cars, nfolds=5)

# rename the column "fold_numbers"
names(fold_numbers) <- "fold_numbers"

# print the fold_assignment column
print(fold_numbers)

# append the fold_numbers column to the cars dataset
cars <- h2o.cbind(cars,fold_numbers)

# try using the fold_column parameter:
cars_gbm <- h2o.gbm(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = cars,
                    fold_column="fold_numbers", seed = 1234)

# print the auc for your model
print(h2o.auc(cars_gbm, xval = TRUE))
```

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks. I wish there was a more general way to do it, regardless of whether cross-validation was chosen (I.e.: something that could be specified in `h2o.splitFrame()`, which would cover the simplest case with one training and one validation set).